# Pasar datos de una tabla a otra con campos diferentes SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla llamada tbl_prestamo que tiene los siguientes campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero realizar una inserción de todos los datos de un registro a otra tabla llamada *tbl_pre_devueltos*, que tiene casi los mismos campos solo que algunos se llaman de forma diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como puedo hacerlo o al menos me sale todo el rato el error que la clave principal esta vacía.

Un saludo.

Comment: Sugiero que, si hay un error, en tu pregunta incluyas el código que produce el error y el mensaje exacto del mismo. (texto, no imagenes). Un salduo.

Comment: Tu edición debiera ser, en realidad, una nueva pregunta. StackOverflow no permite más de una pregunta en una pregunta (parece obvio, ¿no?). Por esa misma razón, y porque ya tienes una respuesta aceptada, estoy revirtiendo tu edición a la misma y te invito a escribir esa duda en una nueva. Para más informacion, lee [ask]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haz un Insert into select

```
INSERT INTO tabla_destino (campo1,campo2,campo3) SELECT campo_equivalente1,campo_equivalente2,campo_equivalente3 FROM tabla_antigua
```

Si te das cuenta debes poner el mismo orden de los campos en la tabla nueva que en la vieja si te falta algun campo omitelo ambos.

Ten en cuenta que deben coincidir en tipo.